# Pass a pointer for getting result through CFFI

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, cffi

Here's a function in C:

```
union Example {
    int number;
    void *pointer;
};
void return_a_value (union Example *ptr) {
    (*ptr).number = 1;
}
```

Now I want to call it in Common Lisp through CFFI, how can I do it?

```
(defcunion Example 
  (number :int)
  (ptr :pointer))

(defcfun "return_a_value" :void
  (retval :pointer)) ; I'm not very sure here..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's alright up to this point, including your definition of
`return_a_value`. That's how you may call the function:

```
(with-foreign-object (arg 'example)
  (setf (foreign-slot-value arg 'example 'number) 123)
  (return-a-value arg)
  (foreign-slot-value arg 'example 'number))
```