# How to call a foreign function with an output pointer argument?

Tags: common-lisp, cffi

Let’s say there is a C function:

```c
int do_something(int *output);
```

I can define it in lisp with cffi like this:

```lisp
(cffi:defcfun ("do_something" %do-something)
   :int
   (output :pointer))
```

How can I call it and get the value of `output`? I have looked at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979656/pass-a-pointer-for-getting-result-through-cffi), but these are dealing with structs or unions, both of which do not apply in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your answer you probably have a memory leak because the allocated memory is never freed. See `cffi:foreign-free` which is used to *"Free a PTR allocated by FOREIGN-ALLOC."*. Typically you can use `unwind-protect` to call `foreign-free`:

```
(let ((output (cffi:foreign-alloc :int)))
  (unwind-protect (progn ...)
    (cffi:foreign-free output)))
```

Alternatively, you can use the following macro:

```
(cffi:with-foreign-object (output :int)
   ...)
```

Note that if you expand the macro it seems to be able to allocate memory on the stack (tested with SBCL), unlike the above version with `foreign-alloc` and `foreign-free`. I think these two functions are best used in cases where the lifetime of the object is more complex than what a lexical scope offers.

Comment: `with-foreign-object` did not work for me when I tried it, `output` was always `0`.

Comment: If you post the exact code you tried someone might be able to reproduce your problem and maybe see what is going on

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out myself. `cffi:foreign-alloc` allows one to create an int, and `cffi:mem-aref` can be used to access the value, e.g.:

```lisp
(let ((output (cffi:foreign-alloc :int)))
  (%do-something output)
  (format t "Result: ~a~%" (cffi:mem-aref output :int)))
```